# Automatic command insertion for successive capital letters

Tags: macros, scaling, automation

I work in a field with heavy use of acronyms. To make my documents visually more appealing, I like to use a moderate downscaling of the capital letters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\acr}[1]{\protect\scalebox{.93}{#1}}        

\begin{document}

Just a few words to see the scaling of an acronym such as \acr{GEP}. With the scaling, the acronym obviously blends in better with the rest of the text.

\end{document}
```

For several reasons (e.g. exchange with coauthors), I would prefer the insertion of the command to happen automatically – e.g. just writing "of an acronym such as GEP". This would require (La?)TeX to automatically find successive capital letters and insert a previously defined macro.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

(Extra points if the scaling factor of `\scalebox` could depend on the number of successive capital letters.)

Comment: That sounds more like a problem for `sed` or `awk` (or `Perl`, etc.).  There is also the LaTeX3 package `l3regex`, but I haven't looked at it yet, so I don't really know how relevant it might be....

Comment: No, it's not possible to make LaTeX recognize clusters of letters as acronyms. Using a macro is necessary and also better, because you're marking exactly what you want.

Comment: Aside: shrinking capital letters is a poor substitute for a real small caps shape.

Comment: @JosephWright: I guess he don’t wants small caps but smaller caps ;-) They should be recognized as real caps but a little (0.93 times) smaller than the normal caps, because otherwise they stand out on the page. And it’s not that uncommon do do it …

Comment: @Tobi Yes, but that's a decision for the font designer :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Hm … lets assume a font size of 12pt and a font where the upper case letters are the same hight as the font size, The could look right for words beginning with a capital, since there’s only one capital letter, but in an acronym there are many more and scaling them to 11.5pt can be a good idea to make them look the same size as the rest of the text (-> grey level). I guess there are ways in OpenType to build this into the font, but not all fonts will have such features …

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @JosephWright – I prefer slightly down-scaled capitals to small-caps for two reasons. Many fonts have 'true' small-caps which are nevertheless very poorly designed (e.g. TeX Gyre Termes, TeX Gyre Pagella). The second reason is that even properly designed small-caps can be 'irritatingly small' in scientific contexts. If you have SCs with x-height, this might be odd for readers that are used to have full-sized capital acronyms, while down-scaled capitals would go unnoticed. This works especially well for Times which has extremely heavy capital letters in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to do what you ask for, unless you completely change TeX's way of parsing input, examining token by token the text. However I'm afraid this would break infinitely many constructions of LaTeX. It *might* be possible with LuaTeX, but some expert's advice would be needed.

Marking the input with a macro is the really practical way.